# Why is dune using ocamlc when I asked to use ocamlopt?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

```
$ dune build ./src/main.exe --profile=release
      ocamlc src/.main.eobjs/byte/ast.{cmi,cmo,cmt} (exit 2)
(cd _build/default && /usr/bin/ocamlc.opt -w -40 -O3 -g -bin-annot -I src/.main.eobjs/byte -I /home/jackprograms/.opam/default/lib/cairo2 -I /home/jackprograms/.opam/default/lib/lablgtk3 -I /usr/lib/ocaml/threads -no-alias-deps -o src/.main.eobjs/byte/ast.cmo -c -impl src/ast.ml)
/usr/bin/ocamlc.opt: unknown option '-O3'.
```

I ran this, and dune is using ocamlc bytecode... I am using `exe` which means native, as I saw on the dune documentation. Why is it running ocamlc when it should be running ocamlopt?

```
(executable
 (name main)
 (libraries lablgtk3)
 (modes exe))

(ocamllex
 (modules lexer))

(ocamlyacc
 (modules parser))

(env
 (dev
  (flags (:standard -w +42)))
 (release
  (flags (:standard -O3))))
```

^ In `src` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will still use `ocamlc` to compile `.cmi` files.

Instead of using `flags` (e.g. `(flags (:standard -O3))`), use `ocamlopt_flags`.

```
(executable
 (name main)
 (libraries lablgtk3)
 (modes exe))

(ocamllex
 (modules lexer))

(ocamlyacc
 (modules parser))

(env
 (dev
  (flags (:standard -w +42)))
 (release
  (ocamlopt_flags (:standard -O3))))
```